# Remove square brackets if content within the square bracket does not contain spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, notepad++

I have a requirement where in I need to convert sql from 1 format to another format.

Below is the sample example

```
select [Project_ID] AS [Project ID]
```

Convert the above line to:

```
select Project_ID AS "Project ID"
```

So the way I am thinking is 2 step strategy

1. If I can somehow remove the [] for the 1s which does not have spaces in between. May be via Regex
2. Replace [ and ] with " for the rest 1s.

I have more than 10K lines of code which needs to be changed.  Manual work would take me a lot of time to get this thing done.

Comment: do you have access to sed or AWK ?

Comment: nop..working on windows for now.. Dont have Unix box..

Comment: but if you know how to get it done using sed or awk, please tell me, i can try and get the box somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do both replacements in a single step:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\[(\w+)\]|\[([^\]]+)\]`
- Replace with: `(?1$1:(?2"$2"))`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
  \[            # opening square bracket
  (\w+)         # group 1, 1 or more word character
  \]            # closing square bracket
|           # OR
  \[            # opening square bracket
  ([^\]]+)      # group 2, 1 or more any character that is not a closing bracket
  \]            # closing square bracket
```

**Replacement:**

```
(?1             # if group 1 exists:
  $1              # replace with content of group 1
  :             # else
  (?2             # if group 2 exists:
    "$2"            # replace with content of group 2 suround with quotes
  )               # endif group 2
)               # endif group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: This is a brilliant solution! Thanks mate!

Comment: @SagarMorakhia: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

You can use two regular expressions to get the desired format.

Follow these steps:

1. Backup your main file. DO this in another temp file.
2. Do Ctrl + H and select "Regular expressions" in search mode
3. write in "find what" box: (?i)(?<=select)\s+[|]\s+(?=as)

   - then click replce all.
4. write in "find what" box: [([^[]]+)]

   - put in "replace box" and click replace all:  "\1"

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple task for two regular expression replaces.

First replace `\[([^\[\] \r\n]+)\]` with `$1`. This removes the brackets from non-space strings.

Next replace `\[([^\[\] \r\n]+ [^\[\]\r\n]+)\]` with `"$1"`. This replaces brackets with double quotes on strings with spaces.

Note both replacements include `\[\]` and `\r\n`. There restricts the replacements to strings that do not themselves contain brackets and to strings that do not contain newlines.

Please make a backup of your file before doing this sort of edit. Because the above does two separate replaces it is possible that lines that have nested brackets will be treated wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the lines of code are in the same format as `select [Project_ID] AS [Project ID]` then you can do this in the following order:

1: Replace `] as [` with `AS "`  -- (Space AS ")

2: Replace `[` with   -- (Space)

3: Replace `]` with `"`

**EDIT:**

If the data is in a mixed format:
`select [Project_ID] AS [Project ID]` and perhaps 
`select [Project_ID] [Project ID]`

then you can do this in the following order:

1: Replace `] as [` with `AS "`  -- (Space AS ")

2: Replace `] [` with `"`  -- (Space ")

3: Replace `[` with   -- (Space)

4: Replace `]` with `"`

Answer (score 0):

Not the  most efficient way. But OP is fine with `awk`

```
 awk -F'['  '{gsub(/\]/ , "", $2); gsub(/\]/ ,"" ,$3);  $3="\042"$3"\042"; print}'   ;
```

Demo :

```
$echo "select [Project_ID] AS [Project ID]" | awk -F'['  '{gsub(/\]/ , "", $2); gsub(/\]/ ,"" ,$3);  $3="\042"$3"\042"; print}'   ;
select  Project_ID AS  "Project ID"
$
```

Explanation :

```
awk -F'[' -- Set delimiter as  "["

gsub(/\]/ , "", $2); -- Replace ]  with "" in second field. We pass regular expression between / / and \ - is escape character 

gsub(/\]/ ,"" ,$3) -- Remove ] from third field. 


 $3="\042"$3"\042"  -- Concat double quotes at start and end of 3rd field.
```